# Create one general interface for GUI, have it implemented by many classes

Tags: java, interface, implementation

I'm just writing an Application which consists out of 3 layers (GUI, AppLogic, DatabaseQueries).
I want my GUI to communicate with the AppLogic just via interfaces (as it is common practice i guess).
I'd like to have just one interface in the AppLogic that defines all the methods that the GUI can call. 
In my AppLogic I want many classes to implement this interface.
So in my Controller class I´d like to create one instance of whatever is implementing the interface that the GUI can use to call the AppLogic Methods.

```
public interface AppControllerInterface {

    public void m1();
    public void m2();
    public void m3();
    public void m4();
    public void m4();

}

public class M1 implements AppControllerInterface{

    public void m1(){};

}

public class M2 implements AppControllerInterface{

    public void m2(){};

}  

...and so on
```

So, I'd like to specify as many classes as i want and create only one instance with which the GUI controller can call it´s methods

```
AppControllerInterface appCI = new WHATHERE???();
```

I'm aware of the face that I cannot do this the way I am thinking but maybe somebody knows how to solve this somehow. And apart from this, is there any reason for creating multiple interfaces for communicating with other layers?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Your text of what you are intending to do makes sense, but your code sample doesn't match what you wrote. Your code sample implies you want to implement 1 method in 1 class and another method in another class which isn't supported by java. Seems what you are trying to describe would be something like the [facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

Comment: [Dependency injection.](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) Have some external bootstrapper class decide which implementation is used, and inject it into the GUI class through the constructor or a setter.

Comment: Also, one important reason why you'd create interfaces is testability. Coding against an interface makes it much easier to create a mock implementation without having to muck with bytecode engineering. Generally the "you might want to swap out the implementation" is a bit of a red herring, I've never seen that done in practice. (Not saying that it never happens, just that you might not be working on applications with a lifetime long enough to warrant, say, completely reimplementing the data access layer.)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Model-View-Controller (MVC). This pattern should assist you with separating your business logic, database, and graphical elements.

To quote Martin Fowler:

> "At the heart of MVC is what I call Separated Presentation. The idea
>   behind Separated Presentation is to make a clear division between
>   domain objects that model our perception of the real world, and
>   presentation objects that are the GUI elements we see on the screen.
>   Domain objects should be completely self contained and work without
>   reference to the presentation, they should also be able to support
>   multiple presentations, possibly simultaneously."

The following demonstrates a very primitive example of building these layers:

**DefaultController.java** - runs the show. Creates the view(s) and model(s). Instantiates the applications (via main method).

```
public class DefaultController
{
    final DefaultView view = new DefaultView();
    final DefaultModel model = new DefaultModel();

    public JFrame init()
    {
        this.view.addButtonActionListener(new ButtonAction(this.view, this.model));
        return this.view;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new DefaultController().init().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**ButtonAction.java** - not shown, but would implement `ActionListener` and handle the button click. It takes the model and the view as parameters because it may update the model or the view based on the event. The ButtonAction can be considered an extension of the controller.

**DefaultModel.java** - contains data that is presented (e.g. form values, connection settings, etc.).

```
public class DefaultModel
{
    boolean buttonClicked = false;

    public void setButtonClicked(boolean clicked)
    {
        this.buttonClicked = clicked;
    }

    public boolean getButtonClicked()
    {
        return this.buttonClicked;
    }
}
```

**DefaultView.java** - the actual display. This could be graphical or text-based. Assume that the example below contains a `JButton` labeled `button`.

```
public class DefaultView extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    // ... auto generated code ...

    public void addButtonActionListener(ActionListener listener)
    {
        this.button.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    // Other view controls...
    public void setEnabledButton(boolean enabled)
    {
        this.button.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
}
```

Now, the `DefaultController` registers listeners for the view. It handles creating the view and model and ultimately displaying the view. The Controller only interacts with the view through the `DefaultView` public interface. The same is true with the `DefaultModel`. The `DefaultView` and `DefaultModel` do not interact with one another directly.

There are many different ways of implementing this (you'll find every person implements it slightly different), and a good tutorial can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html).

MVC also has a few different variations (e.g. MVC, MVP, MVVM, etc.) that can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: How is MVC at all relevant here? This is like the textbook example of why link-only answers are problematic.

Comment: @millimoose It sounds like they're interested in architecting an application with a graphical user interface. It also sounds like they're talking about a Model (Database), View (GUI), and Controller (AppLogic)...

Comment: Yes. But the question is "how do I connect those layers?", not "what layers should I make?"

Comment: @millimoose agreed. I'm updating to provide a primitive example.

Comment: Now you've explained how to connect a bunch of classes that have nothing to do with the OP's situation. (Which is having potentially one of many models backing a GUI. Where the model in MVC is, in the OP's code, the `AppLogic` layer represented by the facade interace `AppControllerInterface`.)